# Texstudio keybinding move cursor to column 0

Tags: texstudio

I was editing my keybindings in TexStudio today to change home and end behaviour from beginning and and end of document to beginning and end of line. I made the change, but the "Move cursor to line start" key binding brings the cursor to the start of the current line in the editor and I want the cursor to move to the beginning of the line in the file (column 0). I want similar behaviour for the end key to bring the cursor to the last column of the line in the file.

Is this possible in TexStudio?

Comment: If you press the home or end key twice, the cursor jumps to the first or last column of the current line in the file.

Comment: Thanks. However, I want it to do that with one key press.